# Using an HTML checkbox to put 1 or 0 into a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am using a simple HTML checkbox in a form to put a 1 for checked and a 0 for unchecked in a field called "subcheck" in a MySQL table.

Does the checkbox default to 1 for "checked" and 0 for unchecked?  If not, how can I give it those values?

Form:

```
<div class="subcheck"><INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="subcheck">Click here to receive free money in the mail.<P></div>
```

In the file the form goes to:

```
$subcheck = $_POST['subcheck'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO submission VALUES (NULL, '$uid', '$title', '$slug', '$cleanurl', '$displayurl', NULL, '$subcheck')");
```

The MySQL table:

```
`submission` (
  `submissionid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `loginid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `displayurl` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `datesubmitted` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `subcheck` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`submissionid`)
)
```

Comment: Please consider sanitizing your inputs before inserting into the database

Comment: Adding to irishbuzz, doing this the way you have presented it asking for trouble. Google "little bobby tables".

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If the checkbox isn't ticked then nothing is sent to the server. Instead, you can provide a default value with:

```
$subcheck = (isset($_POST['subcheck'])) ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 46):

To be sure that always 1 or 0 is sent, you can insert an input hidden with the same `name` of the checkbox in the html:

```
//The input hidden
<input type="hidden" name="subcheck" value="0" />

//The checkbox
<input type="checkbox" name="subcheck" value="1" />
```

This way, you don't need to check in server side if the textbox is set or not ;)

Comment: nice solution, never thought using it that way. People using that should just make sure to keep the hidden input type before the checkbox within the source.

Comment: This works well. Not completely tested yet but so far so good.

Comment: Unfortunately in ColdFusion this will post an array if the checkbox is checked ("[0, 1]")

Comment: Genius! Simply genius!

Answer (score 1):

If Checkbox is unchecked then $subcheck is not submited at all.

In PHP you should write:

```
if !(isset($_POST['subcheck']))
  $subcheck = 0;

mysql_query("INSERT INTO submission VALUES (NULL, '$uid', '$title', '$slug', '$cleanurl', '$displayurl', NULL, '$subcheck')");
```

Answer (score 0):

u should try if statement or **ternary** condition statement..
if(isset($_POST['subcheck']))
$subcheck = 1;
else
$subcheck = 0;

or u can try
$subcheck = (isset($_POST['subcheck'])) ? 1 : 0;

and in database u should use enum type for **subcheck**

Comment: This does not work as the value is not sent if there is not checked attribute applied to the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

This can be used as follows

#### on form page

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="status" value="1" >
```

#### on processing page

```
    $status = (isset($_REQUEST['status']));
    if ($status == 1 )
      {
        $status = 1;
      }
    else
     {
       $status = 0;
     }
   echo $status;
```