# Turn textfield into a checkbox

Tags: php, checkbox

sorry for the vague question before.  I'll try and make it clearer this time.

Currently my admin page has this code, which I want to adapt;

```
  <div> 
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'featured'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'featured',array('size'=>1,'maxlength'=>1)) ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'featured'); ?>
    </div>
```

This currently brings back the featured field which is a 0 or a 1.  Currently I can change the textbox to a 0 or a 1, and this in turn works fine when I press the Save button.  But I want the textField to become a checkbox instead (If I change the middle line to checkbox this changes the type to a tickbox).

How do I change it so that if it's checked it will equal 1 or unchecked it will equal 0?

Thanks

Comment: I think you can submit a hidden value of 0. But this is a widely discussed topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what framework or template engine you use so, I think the better is:

## Solution 1: mysql default

You can change your field type:

```
// or default 0
ALTER TABLE your_table CHANGE COLUMN featured boolean not null default 1;
```

Or, if in your create table:

```
drop table if exists your_table;
create table your_table (
  id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  featured boolean not null default 1,
  -- other fields here
);
```

## Solution 2: [@Strawberry comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21383635/turn-textfield-into-a-checkbox#comment32250008_21383635)

Like [@Strawberry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529673/strawberry) say, you can try that too: [Using an HTML checkbox to put 1 or 0 into a MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675900/using-an-html-checkbox-to-put-1-or-0-into-a-mysql-table)

## Solution 3: manually

Validate with javascript or in your controller/php page the value, and set manually before save.

Comment: Thanks all for your answer, I've just tried something on the off chance and it works!  It appears to be running on something called yii framework! I change the textfield to chechbox and luckily it enters a 1 for checked or 0 for unchecked!

Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @gbrooks Congratulations. So the correctly is: post your answer here or if my answer help you mark as solved.